# pass C# object between aspx pages

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am creating an ASPX application that collects data from the user can creates a file based on this data. Different types of data are collected based on the type of user. Also, I have to check the database to see if there is data already in the database. I am looking for an easy way to keep track of the data while traversing between all the ASPX pages that are collecting data. I know i can pass the data in the URL and if i don't find an alternative method then i will use that.

My question is, is it possible put the data into a C# object and somehow pass the instance of that object between ASPX pages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest is to use the Session bag.

```
Session["FirstName"] = FirstNameTextBox.Text;
Session["LastName"] = LastNameTextBox.Text;
```

When retrieving an object from session state, cast it to the appropriate type.

```
ArrayList stockPicks = (ArrayList)Session["StockPicks"];
```

Here's a more exhaustive article on Session state on MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx (from which the brief code examples are shamelessly copied)

Comment: Thank you for that. I think i will use Session, it seems like a solution that will fit what im trying to do. Also, are you saying that you cannot pass C# objects to ASPX pages?

Comment: I apologise if I'm unclear - you can put any object you like in Session with some caveats, explained in the article in more detail. :)

Comment: Thank you, i hadn't started reading the article when i asked. Thank you for your help.

Comment: With one exception: It's kind of restricted to inproc sessions. When using other methods (sql server, state server etc.) everything in the session state has to be serialized, and many objects are not possible to serialize.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the data is not prohibitively big, I'd put the data in `Session` and retrieve it from page to page.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Session object for this.